# WCAG G127 Sufficient Technique

Tags: accessibility, wcag, wcag2.0

In G127 sufficient technique (https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G127.html#G127-tests), What does one mean by the second step of the procedure mentioned in the test, ie, 'Check if the Web page includes metadata identifying the Web page's relationship to the collection to which it belongs.'?

The G127 is sufficient technique of Success Criteria 2.4.8(Location), where under that sufficient technique, H59 sufficient technique (http://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20161007/H59) is mentioned.

Is that the solution to test for G127? If not, what is the solution, to check and verify for G127?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"2.4.8: Location" is the **success criterion**

This success criteria has 4 **sufficient techniques**:

- [G65: Providing a breadcrumb trail](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/general/G65.html)
- [G63: Providing a site map](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/general/G63.html)
- [G128: Indicating current location within navigation bars](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/general/G128.html)
- [G127: Identifying a Web page's relationship to a larger collection of Web pages](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/general/G127.html)

You have to follow G127 if your content is part of a large collection of a page :

- a chapter in a Book,
- a step in a process.

In order to resolve G127 sufficient techniques **AND** if you use HTML, you can use the H59 **technique** to solve a subpart of what G127 concerns. Note that [its user agent support is very low](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/Techniques/ua-notes/html#H59)

If your content is not part of a large collection of pages, providing a breadcrumb trail (G65) is the more common solution.

But it's not because it's sufficient that you should not indicate the current location in navigation bars (G128), or that you can not implement a custom navigation bar to identify  page's relationship to a larger collection of Web pages.

Comment: Can you clarify on the role of the step 2 under the  test procedure mentioned in G127, ie, Check if the Web page includes metadata identifying the Web page's relationship to the collection to which it belongs.'

Comment: @Austine Like I said in my answer, if you are rendering an HTML web page, this is what the HTML H59 technique focuses on. As I can't find any good example of a web page not being HTML, you might consider the "step 2" as an equivalent of the H59 technique.

Comment: The distinction exists only because "G" techniques are "General techniques" (applicable to any language), while "H" techniques are "HTML techniques"...